# PHP get output stream or just echo

Tags: php

What would be the differnce in php command line app of just echoing or printf etc some string as opposed to getting sdtout stream and writing to it i.e.

```
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
```

Comment: stdout being the IO stream of functions like echo and printr I would say there is not real difference other than accessing it directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind for me is output buffering. `echo` and `print` interface with the output buffering mechanism, but directly writing to stdout bypasses it.

Consider this script:

```
<?php
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
ob_start();
        echo "echo output\n";
        fwrite($stdout, "FWRITTEN\n");
        echo "Also echo\n";
$out = ob_get_clean();
echo $out;
```

which outputs:

```
FWRITTEN
echo output
Also echo
```

which demonstrates that `echo` is buffered, and fwrite is not.

Comment: Here `php://stdout` is not buffered stream, fwrite can buffer the output using `php://output`

Comment: nice answer. it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `echo` writes to `php://output` which is the output buffer stream.
However, `php://stdout` gives you direct access to the processes' output stream which is unbuffered.

Further information regarding streams can be found in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already noted technical difference, there's also the obvious difference in style and convention.  `echo`/`print` is the normal way of producing output in PHP; writing to output as if to a file would be abnormal and potentially confusing.  For the sake of the clarity of your intent, I wouldn't advise doing this unless you have a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Here `php://stdout` is not buffered stream, fwrite can buffer the output using `php://output`